# CSGO: Laggy on Linux

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, linux, ubuntu

Today I fired up Counter Strike Global Offensive for the first time in almost a year. Great to be back but I'm noticing some lag while playing the game locally with bots only. My system specs seem to meet the game requirements, which I've included below.

Any advice on fine-tuning my system so the game runs smoothly like it used to?

**CSGO Requirements:**

[image]

**System Specs:**

[image]

**Video Driver:**

[image]

**CSGO Video Settings (tried Reset Defaults but still laggy):**

[image]

**CPU Performance**

[image]

**Steam detects the built-in Video Card, not GTX 1050 Ti ?:**

[image]

**Nvidia X Settings:**

[image]

**Output of mat_info command while ingame:**

```
ShaderAPI: shaderapidx9
Shader API Driver Info:

Driver : OpenGL (null) ((null)) Version : 0
Driver Description :  (null) ((null)) (null) - 1920x1080
Chipset version 1 2 0 0

Display mode : 1920 x 1080 @0Hz (BGRX8888)
Vertex Shader Version : 3.0 Pixel Shader Version : 3.0

Device Caps :
CANBLTSYSTONONLOCAL  N  CANRENDERAFTERFLIP  N  HWRASTERIZATION *N*
HWTRANSFORMANDLIGHT  Y  NPATCHES  N  PUREDEVICE  N 
SEPARATETEXTUREMEMORIES  N  TEXTURENONLOCALVIDMEM  N  TEXTURESYSTEMMEMORY  N 
TEXTUREVIDEOMEMORY *N* TLVERTEXSYSTEMMEMORY *N* TLVERTEXVIDEOMEMORY  N 

Primitive Caps :
BLENDOP  N  CLIPPLANESCALEDPOINTS  N  CLIPTLVERTS  N 
COLORWRITEENABLE  N  MASKZ *N* TSSARGTEMP  N 

Raster Caps :
FOGRANGE  N  FOGTABLE  N  FOGVERTEX  N  ZFOG  N  WFOG  N 
MIPMAPLODBIAS  N  WBUFFER  N  ZBIAS  Y  ZTEST *N*
Size of Texture Memory : 524288 kb
Max Texture Dimensions : 4096 x 4096
Max Textures : 0

Texture Caps :
ALPHA  N  CUBEMAP  Y  MIPCUBEMAP  Y  SQUAREONLY  N 
vendor id: 0x1
device id: 0x2
SHADERAPI CAPS:
m_NumSamplers: 16
m_NumVertexSamplers: 4
m_HasSetDeviceGammaRamp: no
m_SupportsPixelShaders_2_b: yes
m_SupportsShaderModel_3_0: yes
m_SupportsCompressedVertices: 1
m_bSupportsAnisotropicFiltering: yes
m_nMaxAnisotropy: 16
m_MaxTextureWidth: 4096
m_MaxTextureHeight: 4096
m_MaxTextureAspectRatio: 4096
m_MaxPrimitiveCount: 32768
m_ZBiasAndSlopeScaledDepthBiasSupported: yes
m_NumPixelShaderConstants: 224
m_NumVertexShaderConstants: 256
m_NumBooleanVertexShaderConstants: 16
m_NumIntegerVertexShaderConstants: 16
m_TextureMemorySize: 536870912
m_MaxNumLights: 4
m_MaxVertexShaderBlendMatrices: 53
m_SupportsMipmappedCubemaps: yes
m_nDXSupportLevel: 95
m_PreferDynamicTextures: yes
m_MaxUserClipPlanes: 2
m_SupportsSRGB: yes
m_HDRType: HDR_TYPE_INTEGER
m_UseFastClipping: no
m_pShaderDLL: 
m_bNeedsATICentroidHack: no
m_bDisableShaderOptimizations: no
m_MaxSimultaneousRenderTargets: 1
m_bPreferZPrepass: no
m_bSuppressPixelShaderCentroidHackFixup: no
m_bPreferTexturesInHWMemory: yes
m_bPreferHardwareSync: yes
m_bSupportsNPO2Textures: yes
m_bUnsupported: no
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see a mobile card, is that a laptop? Some laptops use one video card for the built in display, but then a separate one for an external connection (HDMI for example). Do you have the model of the device?

Comment: Steam has this linux specific issue for like a decade now and it doesn't look like it will ever get fixed. What does it say ingame (console -> mat_info)? And you should be able to force the correct card with your NVidia controls if it's actually wrong (or in BIOS as last resort). If that still doesn't help  try fps_max 0 or play around with vsync, screen refresh rate, etc.

Comment: @Sorean Good catch. Yep, it's a Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7567.

Comment: @dly Thanks for the troubleshooting tips. I updated my post to include the output of the `mat_info` command, at the bottom.

Comment: How about lowering your settings? Especially MSAA. I don't think mobile CPU/GPU can't handle that much of high settings. Auto settings can be absolute trash.

Comment: @Skye-AT Good idea. Today I tried setting all of the video settings to low and disabled MSAA. I was surprised the game still feels laggy.

Comment: Are you on Wayland or X11? Update your post to include the answer. If you're on Wayland, try switching to X11. If that fixes it, post it as the answer, then open a new question asking why CSGO is laggy on Linux+Wayland. Good luck!